# Error Message: Could not find jsonapi-parser-0.1.1.beta2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Error showing while I am trying to deploy rails 5 application in AWS server.

Error Message: *Could not find jsonapi-parser-0.1.1.beta2 in any of the sources*

My local machine is ubuntu and it works perfectly.

Official gemfile page showing 'This version has been yanked, and it is not available for download directly or for other gems that may have depended on it.'

https://rubygems.org/gems/jsonapi/versions/0.1.1.beta5

Now how can I resolve this dependency!

Answer (score 0):

Need to update jsonapi gem:

`bundle update jsonapi`